# MATCH function suddenly stopped working

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this VBA macro for Excel code many years ago and it has suddenly stopped working. I'm trying to find the row index in one sheet that exactly matches an entry in the current sheet. The line of code that has stopped working is:

```
Cells(rr, cc + 1).Value = "=MATCH(RC[-1], Num, 0)"
```

I'm not sure what **Num** is, since it isn't referenced anywhere in the macro earlier. In particular, I don't see how it references the worksheet i'm interested in.

Comment: Ctrl+K to the code line and some spell/grammar

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to put a formula into the cell defined by row:=rr, column:=cc+1 then the code really should be,

```
Cells(rr, cc + 1).FORMULAR1C1 = "=MATCH(RC[-1], Num, 0)"
```

(sorry - all caps for emphasis) That formula would make use of a *Named Range* called *Num*. Check Formulas ► Defined Names ► Name Manager for its existence. It will refer to a single row or column of cells where the lookup for the value of one cell to the left is performed.

If you try and put an *xlR1C1* style formula in as the .Value, it *may* be correctly interpreted by the worksheet overhead as a formula. However, without a defined *Num* range, this would produce the `#NAME?` error on the worksheet.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  That didn't help yet.  I may have a simpler problem.  I have noticed that RC[-1] used to return the value of that cell and now it just returns the cell; i.e. in my current example, rr is 23 and cc is 1  It is returning A23 rather than the value of that cell.  Also, when I run the macro the formulas are not being evaluated.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) works. It returns the row number of the match so the named range *Num* must closely duplicate column A. If you want to return a cell's value either from column A or another column use a [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a)/MATCH function pair or possibly [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Comment: Thanks again.  I have noticed that the following formula works well: =MATCH(A22,Num,0) but that =MATCH(A23,Num,0) doesn't.  Both cells A22 and A23 are populated. ???

Comment: Perhaps *Num* only goes to row 22. At some point you are going to have to show some sample data and explain exactly how *Num* is defined.

Comment: OK. I have two sheets in a workbook.  One is the inventory called INVENT and the other is supposed to be a list of sales from a show.  Column C in INVENT is the inventory number.  I just replaced Num with its value and the same thing occured in the show worksheeet.  =MATCH(A22,INVENT!$C:$C,0) works correctly and =MATCH(A23,INVENT!$C:$C,0) fails.

Comment: I also just noticed that the macro works fine in a different show worksheet.  It seems this isn't exactly a VBA question anymore.  Something is weird with this sheet.  I tried copying it into a new sheet, but the same problem happened.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be a bad data entry in the worksheet I was trying to MATCH to.  I don't know why it didn't just return a FALSE value.  However, I have solved my problem thanks to the help from this site.
Thanks.